# Call to undefined function apply_filters in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem with index.php
When I made a program running for the page on the server
I found a message.
This template works well on WordPress, but when I run it on the server, a message appears

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function apply_filters() in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\index.php:15 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\index.php on line 15

```
<?php
/**
 * Index template.
 *
 * @package Neve
 */

/**
 * Filters the container classes.
 *
 * @param string $classes Container classes.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
$container_class = apply_filters( 'neve_container_class_filter', 'container', 'blog-archive' );
get_header();
?>
    <div class="<?php echo esc_attr( $container_class ); ?> archive-container">
        <div class="row">
            <?php
            /**
             * Executes the rendering function for the sidebar.
             *
             * @param string $context Sidebar context.
             * @param string $position Sidebar position.
             *
             * @since 1.0.0
             */
            do_action( 'neve_do_sidebar', 'blog-archive', 'left' );
            ?>
            <div class="nv-index-posts blog col">
                <?php
                /**
                 * Executes actions before the posts loop start.
                 *
                 * @since 2.4.0
                 */
                do_action( 'neve_before_loop' );

                /**
                 * Executes the rendering function for the page header.
                 *
                 * @param string $context Header display page.
                 *
                 * @since 2.3.10
                 */
                do_action( 'neve_page_header', 'index' );

                /**
                 * Executes actions before the post loop.
                 *
                 * @since 2.3.10
                 */
                do_action( 'neve_before_posts_loop' );

                $current_post_type = get_post_type();
                $should_add_hook   = ! in_array( $current_post_type, array( 'post', 'page', 'product' ) );

                if ( have_posts() ) {
                    /* Start the Loop. */
                    echo '<div class="posts-wrapper row">';


                    $pagination_type = get_theme_mod( 'neve_pagination_type', 'number' );
                    if ( $pagination_type !== 'infinite' ) {
                        global $wp_query;

                        $posts_on_current_page = $wp_query->post_count;
                        $hook_after_post       = -1;

                        if ( $posts_on_current_page >= 2 ) {
                            $hook_after_post = (int) ceil( $posts_on_current_page / 2 );
                        }
                        $post_index = 1;
                    }

                    if ( $should_add_hook ) {
                        /**
                         * Executes actions before a post loop.
                         *
                         * The dynamic portion of the hook name, $current_post_type, refers to the post type slug.
                         * This hook is not available for the following post types: post, page, product.
                         *
                         * Possible action names include:
                         * - neve_loop_attachment_before
                         * - neve_loop_acme_product_before
                         *
                         * @since 2.11
                         */
                        do_action( 'neve_loop_' . $current_post_type . '_before' );
                    }

                    while ( have_posts() ) {
                        the_post();

                        if ( $should_add_hook ) {
                            /**
                             * Executes actions before a post loop entry.
                             *
                             * The dynamic portion of the hook name, $current_post_type, refers to the post type slug.
                             * This hook is not available for the following post types: post, page, product.
                             *
                             * Possible action names include:
                             * - neve_loop_attachment_entry_before
                             * - neve_loop_acme_product_entry_before
                             *
                             * @since 2.11
                             */
                            do_action( 'neve_loop_' . $current_post_type . '_entry_before' );
                        }

                        /**
                         * Executes actions before rendering the post content.
                         *
                         * @since 2.11
                         */
                        do_action( 'neve_loop_entry_before' );

                        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_type() );

                        if ( $pagination_type !== 'infinite' ) {
                            if ( $post_index === $hook_after_post && $hook_after_post !== - 1 ) {
                                /**
                                 * Executes actions in the middle of the loop.
                                 *
                                 * The actions only fires if the pagination is not set as "infinite scroll".
                                 *
                                 * @since 2.3.10
                                 */
                                do_action( 'neve_middle_posts_loop' );
                            }
                            $post_index ++;
                        }

                        /**
                         * Executes actions after rendering the post content.
                         *
                         * @since 2.11
                         */
                        do_action( 'neve_loop_entry_after' );

                        if ( $should_add_hook ) {
                            /**
                             * Executes actions after a post loop entry.
                             *
                             * The dynamic portion of the hook name, $current_post_type, refers to the post type slug.
                             * This hook is not available for the following post types: post, page, product.
                             *
                             * Possible action names include:
                             * - neve_loop_attachment_entry_after
                             * - neve_loop_acme_product_entry_after
                             *
                             * @since 2.11
                             */
                            do_action( 'neve_loop_' . $current_post_type . '_entry_after' );
                        }
                    }
                    echo '</div>';
                    if ( ! is_singular() ) {
                        /**
                         * Executes the rendering function for the pagination.
                         *
                         * @param string $context Pagination location context.
                         */
                        do_action( 'neve_do_pagination', 'blog-archive' );
                    }
                } else {
                    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );
                }
                ?>
                <div class="w-100"></div>
                <?php
                /**
                 * Executes actions after the post loop.
                 *
                 * @since 2.3.10
                 */
                do_action( 'neve_after_posts_loop' );

                if ( $should_add_hook ) {
                    /**
                     * Executes actions after a post loop.
                     *
                     * The dynamic portion of the hook name, $current_post_type, refers to the post type slug.
                     * This hook is not available for the following post types: post, page, product.
                     *
                     * Possible action names include:
                     * - neve_loop_attachment_after
                     * - neve_loop_acme_product_after
                     *
                     * @since 2.11
                     */
                    do_action( 'neve_loop_' . $current_post_type . '_after' );
                }
                ?>
            </div>
            <?php
            do_action( 'neve_do_sidebar', 'blog-archive', 'right' );
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
get_footer();
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by “ This template works well on WordPress, but when I run it on the server”

Comment: I mean, the design files just look good
Within the Word Press program

Comment: The function `apply_filters` is a WordPress function, and can only be called in a WordPress context. The file path of your error message does not appear to be a WordPress install/context. Whether WordPress is “installed” or not doesn’t matter, is this URL being activated in a WordPress context?